# Sublime text Autosave only for specific files

Tags: sublimetext2

I don't want to hit `cmd+s` all day when I code a web UI using Sublime Text 2.

**SCENARIO:**

- Sublime Text with LiveStyle plugin
- Google Chrome with Live Style addon

**WHAT I DON'T WANT:**

- Hitting `cmd+s` every time I edit an `html/js/css` file
- Applying a global autosave solution like `"save_on_focus_lost": true` to all files of a project (e.g. python or php files shouldn't be autosaved)

**WHAT I WANT:**
Autosave and automatically reload only certain files of my project in Chrome (thanks to LiveStyle)

**QUESTION:**
How to selective apply an autosave setting (or plugin) like `"save_on_focus_lost": true` only to certain files within a project?

Any alternative solution is welcome

Comment: Good luck with that, i want to know if this is possible too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about LiveStyle, so I'll speak to the autosaving specifically. If it's all files of a particular type, you can create a syntax specific setting. If it isn't you can write a plugin that ties into the `on_load` or `on_activated` event. When this event is triggered, you can apply a setting to the view. Assuming you have the view, you can do something like `view.settings().set("save_on_focus_lost", True)` in the plugin.